# Errors when trying to use any Atribue declarion <Attribute> vb.net

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I get errors when trying to use code that uses attributes

```
Public Class <AttributeUsageAttribute(Of AttributeTargets, AllowMultiple := True)> CustomPermissionAttribute Inherits CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
Private myUnrestricted As Boolean = False End Class
```

When I get the error, VS goes the the first "<". I'm just now starting to use code like this, so I'm basically pretty dumb about it, and any help is appreciated.

thanks for any help...

Comment: That is invalid syntax.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use some snippets I found that has to with security permissions. I'm actually glad that you say it's invalid. Does vb not take code like this. Should I be doing something else? And if so, could you point me in a direction please... thank you

Comment: No; it's just meaningless.  That's a mix of a normal class declaration syntax and attribute application syntax.  You need to learn about VB attributes; see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been referencing this type of code on the Microsoft website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  If you poke around it there, they use this type of code for vb.net. Maybe I'm missing a reference?

Comment: Read more carefully.  The attribute goes above the class declaration.

Comment: Hey... thanks for helping me out. I knew it had to be something basic. I consider this as learning something really important. Thanks for the lesson my friend

Comment: oops... spoke too soon. It still doesn't like the "<". I did move it about the main class. I have to head to bed, but will see if you responded when I get up. Thanks for all your help...

Comment: The code currently in your question is nonsense.  If that is not the code you are currently using then please edit your question and provide the actual code you are currently using so that we can see what's wrong with it.  If what's in the question is your current code then you clearly haven't done as instructed by @SLaks, so doing that would be a good start.

Comment: @jmcihinney Thanks for the feedback. More reading is exactly what I had on my list for today. I will try to edit my question. I will do a better job when it comes to code next time. Thanks again...